# How can i parse this using StringUtils or Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Im currently facing the issue where

```
<a href="<a href="http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output" target="_blank">http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output</a>">Links</a>
```

Is being returned from a service I am using. As you can see this is NOT valid html. Does anyone know any tools or regular expressions that can help me remove the inner  tag to change it to this:

```
<a href="http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output">Links</a>
```

EDIT:
The service does not always return freeformatter.com website. It could return ANY website

Comment: have you tried anything till now?

Comment: Report it to the service provider.

Comment: Ive been trying to use Java.split tool and manually changing it but my solutions seem overly complicated and clunky. 
Will report the service provider but dont really have time to wait for them to make their change

Comment: is jsoup good for parsing invalid html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL or content within the tags changes you'll want to use a more generalized pattern perhaps:

```
(<a\\shref=\"\\w.+\")\\s.+>\"(.+</a>)
```

This essentially captures the portions of the string you want into two groups; which can then be reassembled into one string. Here's a working example:

**http://ideone.com/TbOvVa**

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. Not very strong with regex so this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
String s = "<a href=\"<a href=\"http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output</a>\">Links</a>;
```

(You'll need to save it as a String somehow in your program)

Then:

```
s = s.replace("<a href=\"", "");
String[] pcs = s.split("http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output</a>\">");
s = pcs[0] + pcs[1];
s = s.replace(" target=\"_blank\"", "");
```

You would have the right ref after all this processing.

Comment: oh sorry i wasn't clear. It could be www.xxx. Doesnt have to be freeformatter.com

Answer (score 0):

grab the first a href=" with .substring(0,8)
then use .split("\">",1) and use the resulting array at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Simply use the grouping feature of the regex that is captured by parenthesis `()`. Get the matched group using `Matcher.group()` method.

Find all the occurrence between > and < and combine it as per your need.

Here is the regex pattern `>([^\">].*?)<`. Have a look at the demo on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mqnNza3fcuaZdp8Z) and [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xL9dG4)

Pattern description:

```
.       Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
[^abc]  Any character except a, b, or c (negation)
X*?     X, zero or more times (Reluctant quantifiers)
(X)     X, as a capturing group
```

Read more about

- [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Regex Groups and capturing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

Sample code:

```
String string = "<a href=\"<a href=\"http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output</a>\">Links</a>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(">([^\">].*?)<");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output
Links
```

---

### Solution 2

Try with `String#replaceAll()` method using `(</a>)[^$]|([^^]<a(.*?)>)` regex pattern.

**Pattern says:** Replace all the `</a>` that is not in the end and `<a.*?>` that is not in the beginning with the double quotes.

Find demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iD1mV4) and [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qu2hwVz3-Hkjv02l)

Pictorial representation of this regex pattern:

[image]

Sample code:

```
String string = "<a href=\"<a href=\"http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output</a>\">Links</a>";

System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(</a>)[^$]|([^^]<a(.*?)>)", "\""));
```

output:

```
<a href="http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output">Links</a>
```